# Is there a way to Index a doc to Elasticsearch with a specific _id filed?

Tags: api, elasticsearch, logging, indexing

I'm looking to simulate a state where I have a specific _id field inside an index.

Let's assume I want to take the EXACT same log from index1 in my example and index it into index2.

Like so:

This is my ***index1***

```
{
   _index: "index-number-one",
   _type: "doc",
   _id: "S0meSpec!f!cID",
   _score: 1,
   _source: {
      message: "message1",
      type: "type1",
      tags: [
         "_bla"],
      number: 3
   }
}
```

Now I want that exact same log in my ***index2***

```
{
   _index: "index-number-two",
   _type: "doc",
   _id: "S0meSpec!f!cID",
   _score: 1,
   _source: {
      message: "message1",
      type: "type1",
      tags: [
         "_bla"],
      number: 3
   }
}
```

Couldn't find an API in Elasticsearch that can insert a doc to an Index with a specific _id field... (?)

If this action isn't possible so that the Elasticsearch cluster won't have duplications in the _id field, I can imagine it's because they want to keep the ability to search a doc by it's _id
field which needs to be unique, in that case, assume that I don't mind deleting the entire doc from ***index1*** (maybe save it aside as some variable in my code), but in the end, I need the doc in ***index2***, to have the EXACT _id as ***index1*** once had.

And if there's a way to edit an existing _id field it would also solve my problem.

Can anyone please shed any light on how to achieve that goal?

Comment: There is `meta` attribute which you can pass while indexing a document. Example : I do it from python like this `JiraIndex(meta={'id': 'XYKAL1776reLAO'}, jira_num='AQPEO74', ....)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

answer to myself, 
I found that it can be done in a POST request on the index like so:

```
POST twitter/test-index-1234/abctype/Som3Cust0mID
{
"user" : "kimchy",
"post_date" : "2009-11-15T14:12:12",
"message" : "trying out Elasticsearch"
}
```

And the outcome in ES:

```
{
_index: "test-index-1234",
_type: "abctype",
_id: "Som3Cust0mID",
_score: 1,
_source: {
   user: "kimchy",
   post_date: "2009-11-15T14:12:12",
   message: "trying out Elasticsearch"
   }
}
```

Comment: You probably need to remove `twitter` from your URL

Comment: It was just an example to a host URL like Elasticsearch write on their documentation.

Answer (score 0):

It is definitely possible to do this. IDs are unique per index, not per cluster.

Check the [reindex API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html), it copies one index onto another and **keeps the document IDs**.

It is also possible to change the ID using a script inside the reindex call.